# Disable ShareActionProvider in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm tying to disable `ShareActionProvider` shown in ActionBar's Action Mode. But

```
menu.findItem(R.id.myShareItem).setEnabled(false)
```

does not disables it. Am I missing something or it just can't be disabled ?

UPDATE:

Testing on Jelly Bean, this standalone Activity class demonstrates the problem:

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MenuItem mShareItem;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        ShareActionProvider sap = new ShareActionProvider(this);

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType(MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("jpg"));
        sap.setShareIntent(shareIntent);


        mShareItem = menu.add("Share");
        mShareItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        mShareItem.setActionProvider(sap);

        MenuItem toggleItem = menu.add("Toggle");
        toggleItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        //---shouldn't this work ? -----
        mShareItem.setEnabled(!mShareItem.isEnabled());

        Toast.makeText(this,mShareItem + " enabled: " + mShareItem.isEnabled(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I would have expected that to work. Is there any visual effect at all? Is there anything logged to LogCat? Have you tried this with the native action bar (in case it's a bug with ABS)?

Comment: No logs , `MenuItem` has enabled set to false but I can still click it, currently I'm  making its `ShareIntent` null as a workaround. This happens when in `ActionMode`.

Comment: That's disturbing, and I don't see a bug report on it on b.android.com. If you could put together a sample project demonstrating the issue, I can run some experiments (e.g., test it on native action bar).

Comment: Just tested on Jelly Bean. Issue's there too. I'll put up a demo and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @CommonsWare updated with sample code.

Comment: There's a typo in your code (you are toggling `mShareItem` based upon whether `item` is enabled, not based upon whether `mShareItem` itself is enabled). That being said, even with that fixed, I can reproduce your problem. At the moment, I am going to chalk this up to being a bug, which I have filed: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39290

Comment: @CommonsWare Typo fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a probable bug , [reported here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39290).

Current workaround: `setShareIntent(null)`

Comment: This workaround only works the first time the menu is loaded.  On subsequent loads the menu is still clickable and items in the list are selectable but while the share intent is null items in the menu do nothing.  This is a fairly poor experience for the user as they will see the menu, be able to click an item which will close the menu but nothing will happen thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
setShareIntent(new Intent());
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: This works well in `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)`, not just the first time the menu is loaded. Android 6.0.1.